# Transform position don't change gameObject position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make respawn my player to the spawn point when he has a contact with a projectile. The event `onTriggerEnter` is triggered when the event occurs, but the player position do not changed.
I tried to solve my problem with `other.transform.position = spawnPoint;` and `other.gameObject.transform.localPosition = spawnPoint;` or `other.transform.localPosition = spawnPoint;`  but it does not change anything.

Here is my code :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Projectil : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector3 spawnPoint;
    void Start() {
        spawnPoint = GameObject.Find("SpawnPoint").GetComponent<Transform>().localPosition;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    
        if(other.CompareTag("Player")) {
            other.gameObject.transform.position = spawnPoint;
            Debug.Log("touched : " +  other.transform.position );
        }
    }
}
```

[image: FPSController] [image: 1]

Comment: Just so we're all clear, are you sure that pulling the spawnpoint ```localPosition``` and then setting it as the player's (world) ```position``` is correct?

Comment: I had tried with `spawnPoint = GameObject.Find("SpawnPoint").GetComponent<Transform>().position;`, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: You use a CharacterController which uses physics and a Rigidbody ... in this case you shouldn't do anything via the `Transform` component but rather go through the CharacterController component

Comment: I don't know the other functions to do what I want (I'm a beginner), that's why I use `transform.position`, there is also `CharacterController.Move` but I have the impression that it is not for instant moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When two objects with a physical collider collide, `OnCollisionEnter` is called. Only when one of them is not physical, i.e. `Is Trigger` is set on the collider, then `OnTriggerEnter` is called.

Related Unity Documentation pages:

- [Scripting - Collider.isTrigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html)
- [Manual - Sphere Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SphereCollider.html)